# Split TIME interval around 22:00 time in 2 rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this table

```
+-----+-----+------------+----------+---+
| Row | id  | start_time | end_time |   |
+-----+-----+------------+----------+---+
|   1 | foo | 18:00:00   | 22:00:00 |   |
|   2 | bar | 19:00:00   | 23:00:00 |   |
|   3 | baz | 08:00:00   | 11:00:00 |   |
|   4 | qux | 05:30:00   | 07:30:00 |   |
+-----+-----+------------+----------+---+
```

which can be generated with this

```
WITH TABLE AS (
  SELECT "foo" AS id, TIME(18,0,0) AS start_time, TIME(22,0,0) AS end_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "bar", TIME(19,0,0), TIME(23,0,0)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "baz", TIME(08,0,0), TIME(11,0,0)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "qux", TIME(05,30,0), TIME(07,30,0)
)

SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

If the 22:00 hour is inside the time interval, the row need to be splitted around the hour itself.

For the given input, the output should be:

```
+-----+-----+------------+----------+---+
| Row | id  | start_time | end_time |   |
+-----+-----+------------+----------+---+
|   1 | foo | 18:00:00   | 22:00:00 |   |
|   2 | bar | 19:00:00   | 22:00:00 |   |
|   3 | bar | 22:00:00   | 23:00:00 |   |
|   4 | baz | 08:00:00   | 11:00:00 |   |
|   5 | qux | 05:30:00   | 06:00:00 |   |
|   6 | qux | 06:00:00   | 07:30:00 |   |
+-----+-----+------------+----------+---+
```

Please note that 22:00 hour is used on both start and end of the splitted row.

Also, the same exact behaviour need to be replicated if the hour is 06:00

Can this behaviour be made using directly BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and provides quite generic solution where you can have any number of break points as you need by "enlisting" them in `breaks` expressions

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "foo" AS id, TIME(18,0,0) AS start_time, TIME(22,0,0) AS end_time UNION ALL
  SELECT "bar", TIME(19,0,0), TIME(23,0,0) UNION ALL
  SELECT "baz", TIME(08,0,0), TIME(11,0,0) UNION ALL
  SELECT "qux", TIME(05,30,0), TIME(07,30,0) UNION ALL
  SELECT "xxx", TIME(05,45,0), TIME(23,30,0)
), breaks AS (
  SELECT break FROM UNNEST([TIME(6,0,0), TIME(10,0,0), TIME(22,0,0)]) break
), temp AS (
  SELECT id, start_time, end_time, 
    ARRAY_AGG(break ORDER BY break) break
  FROM `project.dataset.table` CROSS JOIN breaks 
  WHERE break > start_time AND break < end_time 
  GROUP BY id, start_time, end_time
)
SELECT id, point start_time, 
  IFNULL(next_point, point) end_time
FROM (
  SELECT id, point, 
    LEAD(point) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY point) next_point
  FROM temp, UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT([start_time], break, [end_time])) point

)
WHERE NOT next_point IS NULL
-- ORDER BY id, point
```

in above example I set three break points - 06:00, 10:00 and 22:00

and initial intervals as

```sql
Row id      start_time  end_time     
1   bar     19:00:00    23:00:00     
2   baz     08:00:00    11:00:00     
3   foo     18:00:00    22:00:00     
4   qux     05:30:00    07:30:00     
5   xxx     05:45:00    23:30:00
```

and result is:

```sql
Row id      start_time  end_time     
1   bar     19:00:00    22:00:00     
2   bar     22:00:00    23:00:00     
3   baz     08:00:00    10:00:00     
4   baz     10:00:00    11:00:00     
5   qux     05:30:00    06:00:00     
6   qux     06:00:00    07:30:00     
7   xxx     05:45:00    06:00:00     
8   xxx     06:00:00    10:00:00     
9   xxx     10:00:00    22:00:00     
10  xxx     22:00:00    23:30:00
```

Comment: How about the end time is 00.00.00? (end of the day)

Comment: good point - have you tried to adjust code for it? should be doable :o)

Comment: oh, I see your another question  - it might be related to this  - will take a look later today

Comment: I noticed a possibile problem, executing the query exactly as it is posted here, the "foo" id is missing from the output

Comment: Will check this also

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that you can have interval that consists both 06:00 and 22:00 hours so needs to be split on three intervals

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL and allows you to easily (but definitely not elegantly) extend approach to some reasonable (2-5) break points  by cascading same logic for each break point like it is done below

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION split_interval(start_time TIME, end_time TIME, break TIME) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<start_time TIME, end_time TIME>> AS (
  IF(break > start_time AND break < end_time, 
    [STRUCT<start_time TIME, end_time TIME>(start_time, break), (break, end_time)], 
    [STRUCT<start_time TIME, end_time TIME>(start_time, end_time)]
  )
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "foo" AS id, TIME(18,0,0) AS start_time, TIME(22,0,0) AS end_time UNION ALL
  SELECT "bar", TIME(19,0,0), TIME(23,0,0) UNION ALL
  SELECT "baz", TIME(08,0,0), TIME(11,0,0) UNION ALL
  SELECT "qux", TIME(05,30,0), TIME(07,30,0) UNION ALL
  SELECT "xxx", TIME(05,45,0), TIME(23,30,0)
)
SELECT id, new_interval.* FROM (
  SELECT id, new_interval.* FROM `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST(split_interval(start_time, end_time, TIME(22,00,0))) new_interval
),
UNNEST(split_interval(start_time, end_time, TIME(06,00,0))) new_interval
-- ORDER BY id, start_time
```

in above example  - original intervals are as below

```sql
Row id      start_time  end_time     
1   bar     19:00:00    23:00:00     
2   baz     08:00:00    11:00:00     
3   foo     18:00:00    22:00:00     
4   qux     05:30:00    07:30:00     
5   xxx     05:45:00    23:30:00
```

and result is

```sql
Row id      start_time  end_time     
1   bar     19:00:00    22:00:00     
2   bar     22:00:00    23:00:00     
3   baz     08:00:00    11:00:00     
4   foo     18:00:00    22:00:00     
5   qux     05:30:00    06:00:00     
6   qux     06:00:00    07:30:00     
7   xxx     05:45:00    06:00:00     
8   xxx     06:00:00    22:00:00     
9   xxx     22:00:00    23:30:00
```

as you can see here  - if you have 3rd break point - you just need to add yet another outer select around existing - like below

```sql
SELECT id, new_interval.* FROM (
  existing selects ...
),
UNNEST(split_interval(start_time, end_time, TIME(08,00,0))) new_interval
```

it is that part which makes above not elegant enough :o)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
WITH TABLE AS (
  SELECT "foo" AS id, TIME(18,0,0) AS start_time, TIME(22,0,0) AS end_time
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "bar", TIME(19,0,0), TIME(23,0,0)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "baz", TIME(08,0,0), TIME(11,0,0)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "qux", TIME(05,30,0), TIME(07,30,0)
)
SELECT id, intervals.* 
FROM TABLE, 
  UNNEST(IF(
    start_time < TIME '22:00:00' AND end_time > TIME '22:00:00',
    [STRUCT<start_time TIME, end_time TIME>(start_time, TIME '22:00:00'),(TIME '22:00:00',end_time)],
    [STRUCT<start_time TIME, end_time TIME>(start_time, end_time)])) intervals
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of minor adjustements on solution provided from @mikhail-berlyant, and here is the resulting query.

I flagged as `EDIT` in the query the adjustments I made

```
#standardSQL
WITH

`project.dataset.table` AS (
  -- across split point
  SELECT "bar" AS id, TIME(18,0,0) AS start_time, TIME(23,0,0) AS end_time UNION ALL
  -- end at split point
  SELECT "foo", TIME(21,45,0), TIME(22,0,0) UNION ALL
  -- start from split point
  SELECT "fuz", TIME(22,0,0), TIME(23,30,0) UNION ALL
  -- across multiple split points
  SELECT "qux", TIME(05,45,0), TIME(23,30,0) UNION ALL
  -- no split point
  SELECT "quz1", TIME(23,30,0), TIME(23,45,0) UNION ALL
  -- no split point
  SELECT "quz2", TIME(02,0,0), TIME(05,59,0)  
),

breaks AS (
  SELECT break FROM UNNEST([TIME(6,0,0), TIME(22,0,0)]) break
),

temp AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    start_time,
    end_time, 
    ARRAY_AGG(break ORDER BY break) AS break
  FROM `project.dataset.table` CROSS JOIN breaks 
  WHERE
    -- [EDIT] >= instead of > to include rows that starts from split point (`fuz`)
    break >= start_time   
    -- [EDIT] <= instead of < to include rows that ends at split  (`foo`)
    AND break <= end_time  
  GROUP BY id, start_time, end_time
)

SELECT
  id,
  point AS start_time,
  IFNULL(next_point, point) AS end_time

FROM (
  SELECT 
    id,
    point, 
    LEAD(point) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY point) AS next_point
  FROM
    temp,
    UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT([start_time], break, [end_time])) aS point
)

WHERE next_point IS NOT NULL

-- [EDIT] Remove data with same value as start_time/end time (generated from rows that starts from split point or ends at split point, foo/fuz)
AND point != next_point


-- [EDIT] temp table does not handle ids that does not cross to any split point, adding them from main table (`quz1` and `quz2`)
UNION ALL SELECT
  id,
  start_time,
  end_time
FROM  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp)
```

And here is the result

```
+-----+------+------------+----------+---+
| Row |  id  | start_time | end_time |   |
+-----+------+------------+----------+---+
|   1 | bar  | 18:00:00   | 22:00:00 |   |
|   2 | bar  | 22:00:00   | 23:00:00 |   |
|   3 | foo  | 21:45:00   | 22:00:00 |   |
|   4 | fuz  | 22:00:00   | 23:30:00 |   |
|   5 | qux  | 05:45:00   | 06:00:00 |   |
|   6 | qux  | 06:00:00   | 22:00:00 |   |
|   7 | qux  | 22:00:00   | 23:30:00 |   |
|   8 | quz1 | 23:30:00   | 23:45:00 |   |
|   9 | quz2 | 02:00:00   | 05:59:00 |   |
+-----+------+------------+----------+---+
```

---

**EDIT**

If the same input data are created as table (query with destination table)

```
  -- across split point
  SELECT "bar" AS id, TIME(18,0,0) AS start_time, TIME(23,0,0) AS end_time UNION ALL
  -- end at split point
  SELECT "foo", TIME(21,45,0), TIME(22,0,0) UNION ALL
  -- start from split point
  SELECT "fuz", TIME(22,0,0), TIME(23,30,0) UNION ALL
  -- across multiple split points
  SELECT "qux", TIME(05,45,0), TIME(23,30,0) UNION ALL
  -- no split point
  SELECT "quz1", TIME(23,30,0), TIME(23,45,0) UNION ALL
  -- no split point
  SELECT "quz2", TIME(02,0,0), TIME(05,59,0)
```

and then I use the very same table as input for the main query

```
`project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.test`
),
```

executing the main query I'm getting the following error

```
Error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.
```