# Split rows on different days if summing hours value to given day exceeds midnight

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a structure like this

```
+-----+-----+------------+----------+------+----------------------+---+
| Row | id  |    date    |   time   | hour |     description      |   |
+-----+-----+------------+----------+------+----------------------+---+
|   1 | foo | 2018-03-02 | 19:00:00 |    8 | across single day    |   |
|   2 | bar | 2018-03-02 | 23:00:00 |    1 | end at midnight      |   |
|   3 | qux | 2018-03-02 | 10:00:00 |    3 | inside single day    |   |
|   4 | quz | 2018-03-02 | 23:15:00 |    2 | with minutes         |   |
+-----+-----+------------+----------+------+----------------------+---+
```

(I added the `description` column only to understand the context, for analysis purpose is useless)

Here is the statement to generate table

```
WITH table AS ( 
  SELECT "foo" as id, CURRENT_dATE() AS date, TIME(19,0,0) AS time,8 AS hour
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "bar", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(23,0,0), 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "qux", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(10,0,0), 3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "quz", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(23,15,0), 2
) 

SELECT * FROM table
```

Adding the `hour` value to the given time, I need to split the row on multiple ones, if the sum goes on the next day.

**Jumps on multiple days are NOT to be considered**, like +27 hours (this should simplify the scenario)

My initial idea was starting from adding the hours value in a date field, in order to obtain start and end limits of the interval

```
SELECT
  id,
  DATETIME(date, time) AS date_start,
  DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(date, time), INTERVAL hour HOUR) AS date_end
FROM table
```

here is the result

```
+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---+
| Row | id  |     date_start      |      date_end       |   |
+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---+
|   1 | foo | 2018-03-02T19:00:00 | 2018-03-03T03:00:00 |   |
|   2 | bar | 2018-03-02T23:00:00 | 2018-03-03T00:00:00 |   |
|   3 | qux | 2018-03-02T10:00:00 | 2018-03-02T13:00:00 |   |
|   4 | quz | 2018-03-02T23:15:00 | 2018-03-03T01:15:00 |   |
+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+---+
```

but now I'm stuck on how to proceed considering the existing interval.

Starting from this table, the rows should be splitted if the day change, like

```
+-----+-----+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--+
| Row | id  |    date    | hourt_start | hour_end | hours |  |
+-----+-----+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--+
|   1 | foo | 2018-03-02 | 19:00:00    | 00:00:00 |     5 |  |
|   2 | foo | 2018-03-03 | 00:00:00    | 03:00:00 |     3 |  |
|   3 | bar | 2018-03-02 | 23:00:00    | 00:00:00 |     1 |  |
|   4 | qux | 2018-03-02 | 10:00:00    | 13:00:00 |     3 |  |
|   5 | quz | 2018-03-02 | 23:15:00    | 00:00:00 |  0.75 |  |
|   6 | quz | 2018-03-03 | 00:00:00    | 01:15:00 |  1.25 |  |
+-----+-----+------------+-------------+----------+-------+--+
```

I tried to study a similar scenario from an already [analyzed scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952922/1013317), but I was unable to adapt it for handling the day component as well.

My whole final scenario will include both this approach and the other one analyzed in the other question (split on single days and then split on given breaks of hours), but I can approach these 2 themes separately, first query split with day (this question) and then split on time breaks (other question)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem ... I tried the following:

- Create a second table creating all the new rows starting at midnight
- `UNION ALL` it with source table while correcting hours of old rows accordingly

Commented Result:

```sql
WITH table AS ( 
  SELECT "foo" as id, CURRENT_dATE() AS date, TIME(19,0,0) AS time,8 AS hour
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "bar", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(23,0,0), 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "qux", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(10,0,0), 3
) 

,table2 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    -- create datetime, add hours, then cast as date again
    CAST( datetime_add( datetime(date, time), INTERVAL hour HOUR) AS date) date,
    time(0,0,0) AS time -- losing minutes and seconds
    -- substract hours to midnight
    ,hour - (24-EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time)) hour
  FROM
    table
  WHERE
    date != CAST( datetime_add( datetime(date,time), INTERVAL hour HOUR) AS date) )

SELECT
  id
  ,date
  ,time 
  -- correct hour if midnight split
  ,IF(EXTRACT(hour from time)+hour > 24,24-EXTRACT(hour from time),hour) hour
FROM
  table
UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table2
```

Hope, it makes sense.
Of course, if you need to consider jumps over multiple days, the correction fails :)

Comment: I tried your approach and generated a final table with hourstart-hourend-number of hours, but it seems that the minute parte is not managed

Comment: True, but you should be able to implement it with this approach, no?

Comment: I created a reply with a solution started from yours

Comment: I do not understand

Answer (score 1):

Here a possibile solution I came up starting from @Martin Weitzmann approach.

I used 2 different ways:

- ids where there is a "jump" on the day
- ids which are in the same day

and a final `UNION ALL` of the two data

I forgot to mention the first time that the hours value of the input value can be float (portion of hours) so I added that too.

```
#standardSQL
WITH 

input AS (
  -- change of day
  SELECT "bap" as id, CURRENT_dATE() AS date, TIME(19,0,0) AS time, 8.0 AS hour UNION ALL
  -- end at midnight
  SELECT "bar", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(23,0,0), 1.0 UNION ALL
  -- inside single day
  SELECT "foo", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(10,0,0), 3.0 UNION ALL
  -- change of day with minutes and float hours
  SELECT "qux", CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(23,15,0), 2.5 UNION ALL
  -- start from midnight
  SELECT "quz",CURRENT_dATE(), TIME(0,0,0), 4.5
),

-- Calculate end_date and end_time summing hours value    
table AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    date AS start_date,
    time AS start_time,
    EXTRACT(DATE FROM DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(date,time), INTERVAL CAST(hour*3600 AS INT64) SECOND)) AS end_date,
    EXTRACT(TIME FROM DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(date,time), INTERVAL CAST(hour*3600 AS INT64) SECOND)) AS end_time
  FROM input
),

-- portion that start from start_time and end at midnight
start_to_midnight AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    start_time,
    start_date,
    TIME(23,59,59) as end_time,
    start_date as end_date
  FROM
    table
  WHERE end_date > start_date
),

-- portion that start from midnightand end at end_time
midnight_to_end AS (
  SELECT
   id,
   TIME(0,0,0) as start_time,
   end_date as start_date,
   end_time,
   end_date
  FROM
   table
  WHERE
   end_date > start_date 
   -- Avoid rows that starts from 0:0:0 and ends to 0:0:0 (original row ends at 0:0:0)
   AND end_time != TIME(0,0,0)
)

-- Union of the 3 tables
SELECT
  id,
  start_date,
  start_time,
  end_time

FROM (
  SELECT id, start_time, end_time, start_date FROM table WHERE start_date = end_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, start_time, end_time, start_date FROM start_to_midnight
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, start_time, end_time, start_date FROM midnight_to_end
)

ORDER BY id,start_date,start_time
```

Here is the provided output

```
+-----+-----+------------+------------+----------+---+
| Row | id  | start_date | start_time | end_time |   |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+----------+---+
|   1 | bap | 2018-03-03 | 19:00:00   | 23:59:59 |   |
|   2 | bap | 2018-03-04 | 00:00:00   | 03:00:00 |   |
|   3 | bar | 2018-03-03 | 23:00:00   | 23:59:59 |   |
|   4 | foo | 2018-03-03 | 10:00:00   | 13:00:00 |   |
|   5 | qux | 2018-03-03 | 23:15:00   | 23:59:59 |   |
|   6 | qux | 2018-03-04 | 00:00:00   | 01:45:00 |   |
|   7 | quz | 2018-03-03 | 00:00:00   | 04:30:00 |   |
+-----+-----+------------+------------+----------+---+
```